# Can xlsx format be decoded than re-encoded in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

The Excel *xlsx* format is meant to be an open XMl format, however it must be compressed in some way as it is not readable in a text editor.

What I would like to do is convert it to text xml format, allowing me to make an adjustment to it and then reencode it to xlsx  using Java, can this be done ?

More background, I am creating the spreadsheet myself using the Java library and the Apache Poi SXSSF buffered streaming api, this doesnt have the full functionality of the XSSF api but I need to use it because of memory considerations. But my idea is that having created the file, simply converting the file to XML (but not storing as a DOM) and then converting back should not be nearly so memory hungry and would allow me to make further modifications. I don't think jakarta-poi is going to help here I need to use something else.

Comment: you could simply rename the .xlsx into a .zip and then unzip it. The problem is that the zip contains more than 1 file

Comment: @RobertKock what a relevation, its just a zipped file ! -okay I have tried that and found my sheet data in xl/worksheets so my idea looks a real possiblity, thankyou.

Comment: So I made minor edit to one spreadsheet, rezipped and  then renamed to xlsx and it opened ok and showed the change. Now I just need to find a reference to the format

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html#FileFormatInformation for links to the Microsoft information